# Why is my solution to project euler 1 not working?

Tags: java

I decided to just try and get the small example of only going to 10 like the example shown.

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 >and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

```
public class project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int three=0;
        int tot3=0;
        int five=0;
        int tot5=0;
        int total;
        
        while (tot3<10) {
            three+=3;
            tot3=tot3+three;
        };
        while (tot5<10) {
            five+=5;
            tot5=tot5+five;
        };
        
        total=tot3+tot5;
        
        System.out.println("Three's: " + tot3);
        System.out.println("Five's: " + tot5);
        System.out.println("Combined: " + total);
    }

}
```

My output is as show:

> Three's: 18
> Five's: 15
> Combined: 33

Comment: Because your code does nothing like what the question asks it to do. Here's a hint: You're going to need a `for` loop and to use the `modulo` operator (`%`).

Comment: Just a note, you can do this with pencil and paper. 3+6+9+...+999 is 3*333*334/2. 5+10+15+...+1000 is 5*200*201/2. 15+30+45+...+990 is 15*66*67/2. The answer is the sum of 3s plus the sum of 5s minus the sum of 15s.

Comment: see https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/project-euler-1-multiples-of-3-and-5.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class project1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 0;
        int total = 0;

        while (number < 10) {
            System.out.println(number);

            if ((number % 3) == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is a multiple of 3");
                total = total + number; 
            }
            else if ((number % 5) == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is a multiple of 5");
                total = total+number;   
            }
            number++;
        }
        System.out.println("total = "+ total);
    }
}
```

Looking at how slow I was, I did roughly the same thing as everyone else but swapped to a modulus function. The modulus function gives you the remainder(int) of dividing the first number by the second number, and can be compared to another integer. Here I have used it to check if the current number is directly divisible by 3 or 5, and add it to the total if the value is true.

Comment: Uh this is double-counting the numbers divisible by 15. Looks like OP just accepted whatever answer handed them full code on a platter.

Comment: Use `else if` on the 2nd `if`-statement. (:

Comment: Blows my mind that of all the answers, this was the accepted one.

Comment: I think that is because I was both first and did the code for them. Looking back even I don't think I really helped.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers that are both multiples of 3 and 5 (like 15 for instance), are counted twice - once in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (tot3<10) {
        three+=3;
        tot3=tot3+three;
};
```

I think you mean

```
while (tot3<10) {
        three += tot3; // Add this multiple of 3 to the total.
        tot3+=3;       // increment the "next multiple"
    }
```

(same for 5)

Lone nebula also makes a good point - you'd need to add logic to the "5" loop to check it's not already counted in the 3 loop. The mod (%) operator can help there.

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
while (tot3<10) {
    three+=3;
    tot3=tot3+three;
};
while (tot5<10) {
    five+=5;
    tot5=tot5+five;
};
```

This should be

```
while (three<10) {
    three+=3;
    tot3=tot3+three;
};
while (five<10) {
    five+=5;
    tot5=tot5+five;
};
```

Because you're concerned about when you start counting numbers above 10, not when your TOTAL of those numbers is above 10.

Secondly, your solution will count numbers that are a multiple of three and of five twice. For example, 15 will be added twice. Learn about the modulo operator, `%`, to come up with a solution to this (for example, not adding five to the tot5 count if `five % 3 == 0`)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into using the modular operator to solve this problem. In java % will allow you to perform modular arithmetic. For example any multiple of 3 such as 9 % 3 = 0 while 9 % 2 = 1. It can be thought of as what remains after you divide the first number by the second. All multiples of a number modded by that number will return zero.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of your variables through the loop and you'll see the problem:
for tot3

- =3
- =9
- =18
- =30

You're keeping track of the sum, instead of tracking the multiples. This problem is partially solved in by

> while(three<10)

Again, keeping track of the variable through the loop you'll see that this is wrong- it stops at 12, not 9 as you want it. Change it to

> While(three<9) 
>   //ie the last divisible number before the limit, or that limit if its divisible (in the case of 5)

All said, an infinitely more elegant solution would involve modulus and a nice little if statement. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://interviewquizandanswers.blogspot.com/2020/04/project-euler-1-multiples-of-3-and-5.html)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            long n = in.nextLong()-1;
            System.out.println((n-n%3)*(n/3+1)/2 + (n-n%5)*(n/5+1)/2 - (n-n%15)*(n/15+1)/2);
        }
    }
}
```